# Add years to a date column based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with one of the column as date (DATECOL). My target is to increment the years by a "number" but the number is a variable and will be different. This number will be decided on the basis of the values of other columns.

For eg. in SQL this can be implemented as

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN COL1 = "AB" THEN DATEADD(year, 2, DATECOL)
    WHEN COL1 = "XY" AND COL2 = "PQR" THEN DATEADD(year, 2, DATECOL)
    WHEN COL1 = "XY" AND COL2 != "PQR" THEN DATEADD(year, 3, DATECOL)
END AS NEWCOL
FROM DATAFRAME
```

Can someone please help me implement this kind of logic in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for multiple logical conditions and corresponding values:

```
conditions = [(df['COL1'] == 'AB'),
              (df['COL1'] == 'XY') & (df['COL2'] == 'PQR'),
              (df['COL1'] == 'XY') & (df['COL2'] != 'PQR')]

choices = [df['DATECOL'] + pd.DateOffset(years=2),
           df['DATECOL'] + pd.DateOffset(years=2),
           df['DATECOL'] + pd.DateOffset(years=3)]

df['NEWCOL'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.datetime64('NaT'))
```

Comment: this is giving error "invalid type promotion". I dont get why? All the dtypes for 3 series in choices is same. Any idea?

Comment: Add a default for values where no conditions are met. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first ensure your `DATECOL` column is of type [datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['AB', 'XY', 'XY'], 'COL2': ['PQR', 'bla', 'PQR'], 'DATECOL': ['20101001', '20111001', '20121001']})

df['DATECOL'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATECOL'], format='%Y%m%d') #change format as per your need

c1 = df['COL1']=='AB'
c2 = (df['COL1']=='XY') & (df['COL2']=='PQR')
c3 = (df['COL1']=='XY') & (df['COL2']!='PQR')

if len(df[c1]) > 0:
    df.loc[c1, 'DATECOL'] += pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=2)
elif len(df[c2]) > 0:
    df.loc[c2, 'DATECOL'] += pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=2)
elif len(df[c3]) > 0:
    df.loc[c3, 'DATECOL'] += pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=3)
```

Comment: Thank you! The challenge over here is I want some sort of nested if else. If 1st condition doesn't satisfy then move to next (thats why case statement). In the example the 3 conditions are mutually exclusive but that may not be the case all the time.

Comment: Of course! Ah got it. One way to do that would be to add if conditions which check for the number of rows in the dataframe that satisfy a condition. I modified my answer to reflect that change. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What about using np.where with conditions as Akanksha Atrey mentioned?

```py
np.where((first_condition) == True, add_yars, np.where(second_condition) == True, ...)
```